# Web scraping em uma url específica com BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
url = 'http://www.bhaktiyogapura.com/2017/03/calendario-vaisnava-marco-de-2017/'
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                        'Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}



req = requests.get(url,headers= header)

html = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

date = "23 Março 2017- "
for strong in soup.findAll("strong"):
    print (strong.get_text())
    for string in soup.findAll("p", {"class": "event"}):
        print(string.get_text())
```

Estou tentando extrair informações de :  http://www.bhaktiyogapura.com/2017/03/calendario-vaisnava-marco-de-2017

Gostaria de imprimir assim:

```
Dia: 4 Março 2017- Sábado

Evento: Desaparecimento de Śrī Śrīmad Bhakti Vaibhava Purī Gosvāmī Mahārāja
```

Um evento é sempre precedido de "-" como por exemplo,

```
-Início Śrī Navadvīpa-dhāma parikramā e Saṇkalpa grāhāna
```

em Março 2017

O código em questão está imprimindo tudo, ou seja, está ignorando a data.
Eu pretendo também, em vez de colocar a data no código, pegar a data do dia (em local time) e imprimir o evendo daquele dia específico. Como fazer?
 Uma das dificuldades é que as datas estão em português:  1 Março 2017

Comment: ACho que podes começar por aqui: http://ideone.com/VSZf4K

Answer (score 3):

Espero que o código abaixo ajude. Como o HTML da página não é muito consistente o dia 27 de março não foi capturado... Deixei esta exceção para você solucionar pois o 99% do trabalho está resolvido abaixo...:

```
import calendar  
import datetime
import locale

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    


url = ' http://www.bhaktiyogapura.com/2017/03/calendario-vaisnava-marco-de-2017'
site = requests.get(url)

site_HTML = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
dados_calendario = site_HTML.find(attrs={"class": "the_content_wrapper"})

def busca_data_do_evento(evento): 
    ''' A datas estão dentro de uma tag strong. Assim sendo, retornamos a primeira 
    tag p que possui strong antes do eventos'''
    data = evento.find_previous_siblings('p')
    for d in data:
        if d.find('strong'):
            return d    

def busca_eventos(calendario):
    ''' Busca todos o eventos do calendário e retorna em uma lista. Enventos são inciados por '-' ou '–' '''
    eventos = [evento for evento in calendario.find_all('p') if evento.text.startswith('-') or evento.text.startswith('–')]
    return eventos

def trata_eventos(eventos):
    ''' Algumas data possuem eventos divididos em mais de uma tag p, vamos tratar 
        estas situações verificando na página se existem dois eventos seguidos, 
        se existirem agrupamos em um único item '''
    def is_evento(tag):
        if tag.text.startswith('-'):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    eventos_tratados = []
    for n, evento in enumerate(eventos):
        proxima_tag = evento.find_next_sibling('p')
        if is_evento(proxima_tag):
            eventos_tratados.append([evento, proxima_tag])
        else:
            foi_tratado = any([evento in evento_tratado for evento_tratado in eventos_tratados])
            if foi_tratado is False:
                eventos_tratados.append([evento])
    return eventos_tratados

eventos = busca_eventos(dados_calendario)
eventos = trata_eventos(eventos)
calendario = [[busca_data_do_evento(e[0]).text, e] for e in eventos] 

''' Neste ponto temos o calendario com as datas e eventos, contudo os eventos ainda contem ainda estao como objetos Beautifulsoup.
Vamos deixar apenas o texto '''
def get_text(evento):
    return evento.text.strip()

for n, data in enumerate(calendario):
    eventos_data = data[1]
    text_eventos = [get_text(e) for e in eventos_data]
    # altera o calendario deixando apenas texto
    calendario[n][1] = text_eventos   

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Portuguese')
def trata_data(string_data_evento):
    data = string_data_evento.split('-')[0]
    dia, mes, ano = data.split(' ')
    meses = [mes.title() for mes in calendar.month_name]
    mes = str(meses.index(mes))
    data = ''.join([dia, mes, ano])    
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(data, "%d%m%Y").date()

''' Agora vamos tratar as datas e tratar para o formato datetime.date e inseri-las na lista de eventos '''
for n, evento in enumerate(calendario):
    calendario[n].insert(0, trata_data(evento[0]))

''' Finalmente criamos um dicionário para facilitar a busca por data'''
calendario_vaisnava = {}
for evento in calendario:
    calendario_vaisnava[evento[0]] = evento[2][0]
```

Agora vamos ver como ficou a busca em nosso calendário, checando se há eventos no dia 04/03/2017:

```
dia = datetime.datetime.strptime('04032017', "%d%m%Y").date()
print(calendario_vaisnava[dia])
```

Resultado:
    -Desaparecimento de Śrī Śrīmad Bhakti Vaibhava Purī Gosvāmī Mahārāja

IT WORKS!!!